# Basic function is not running using a variable but runs on page load

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to discover why, when resizing the browser window, the function `checkBrowserHeight` is not executing.

Here's the code:

```js
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
      var homeP = document.querySelector('.home-page');
    
      var checkBrowserHeight = function() {
        console.log('function executed');
      }();
    
      window.onresize = checkBrowserHeight;
    }
```

I've set it as a variable so that it loads on page load and then can be called later. Why is this not working, and is there a more optimal way of doing this? Thanks for any help here

Comment: You have assigned the result of calling `function` to `checkBrowserHeight`,  don't put `()` at the end, instead just call again..  `checkBrowserHeight()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two logical problems .

1. there is an extra `()` at the end of the handler function.
2. the handler will be assigned to the `window.onresize` when `window.innerWidth` is wider than 768.

It's my suggestion

```
  var homeP = document.querySelector('.home-page');

  var checkBrowserHeight = function() {
     if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
       console.log('function executed');
     }
  };

  window.onresize = checkBrowserHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var checkBrowserHeight = function() {
    console.log('function executed');
}();
```

Note the parenthesis next to that function's closing bracket. That means you're not assigning `checkBrowserHeight` to the function, you're assigning it to the *result* of the function.

Adding parenthesis to the end of a function calls it. Just remove those, so your code should be:

```
var checkBrowserHeight = function() {
    console.log('function executed');
};
```